# Python: Unable to save matplotlib hist2d plot to file using PdfPages

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I'm trying to save multiple 2D histograms generated using [hist2d](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) to a multipage pdf generated using [PdfPages](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages) using following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import warnings 
import subprocess
import os
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=PendingDeprecationWarning)

x1 = np.random.randn(100000)
y1 = np.random.randn(100000) + 5

pp = PdfPages("somepdf.pdf")
fig = plt.figure()
plt.hist2d(x=x1,y=y2, bins=50)
plt.title(row['smRNAname'])
plt.xlabel("Position(BP)")
plt.ylabel("Read Length")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts in bin')
pp.savefig(fig, dpi=300, transparent = True)
plt.close()

fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.hist2d(x=x1,y=y1, bins=50)
plt.title(row['PIWIname'])
plt.xlabel("Position(BP)")
plt.ylabel("Read Length")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts in bin')
pp.savefig(fig, dpi=300, transparent = True)
plt.close()
pp.close()
```

but I'm getting following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-ccbb61958687> in <module>()
     61     cb = plt.colorbar()
     62     cb.set_label('counts in bin')
---> 63     pp.savefig(fig, dpi=300, transparent = True)
     64     plt.close()
     65 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py in savefig(self, figure, **kwargs)
   2519                 manager = Gcf.get_active()
   2520             else:
-> 2521                 manager = Gcf.get_fig_manager(figure)
   2522             if manager is None:
   2523                 raise ValueError("No figure {}".format(figure))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py in get_fig_manager(cls, num)
     39         figure and return the manager; otherwise return *None*.
     40         """
---> 41         manager = cls.figs.get(num, None)
     42         if manager is not None:
     43             cls.set_active(manager)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Looking from the error itself I can understand that it might be due to the fact that hist2d returns a 2D array instead of referencing to a figure(?).
Saving the histogram directly using plt.savefig("test.pdf") works just fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or it is just not possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.hist2d(x=x1,y=y1, bins=50) <---- here should be plt.hist2d(x=x1,y=y1, bins=50)
plt.title(row['PIWIname'])
```

Let me know if it works:)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I fear that the problem still exists. I guess hist2d is returning something "non-canonical" ?

Comment: Yes but are not supposed to overwrite the fig object. Are you sure that it did not work? You are plotting two figures. The first one gets plotted and the second one not. And check the difference between the plots. In the first one you do not (wrongly) assign to the fig object.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what `hist2d` returns, but the important part here is that it does not return a `matplotlib.figure.Figure`. So if you need to store the return for whatever reason, don't name it `fig` or anything that suggests it would be a figure.